# Local image path in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am not able to get the image path in javascript, below is the code

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
      const themeButton = document.createElement('button')
      if (i === 0)
      {
        themeButton.style.backgroundImage =  "url('../assets/Pngs/ThemesIcon/NewTheme.png')"
        //themeButton.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://i.postimg.cc/wMT2jLG7/Group-4807.png)`
      }
      else
      { 
        themeButton.style.backgroundImage =  "url('../assets/Pngs/ThemesIcon/NewTheme.png')"
      }

     themeButton.classList.add('colorBtn')
      themeButton.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat'
      themeButton.style.backgroundSize = '374px 180px'
     
      container.appendChild(themeButton)
    }
```

if i use url it is  working for local path it is not working.

```
themeButton.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://i.postimg.cc/wMT2jLG7/Group-4807.png)`
```

Folder structure is:

```
App
Files
assets

Files/uiController.js --> i am accessing image
assets/Pngs/ThemesIcon/Theme1.png  --> image folders
```

Comment: the path should be relative to the html page not the js

Comment: the relative path will depend on the path of the page (i.e. what you see in the browsers address bar)

Comment: @JaromandaX i didnt get you

Comment: the path is relative to the current document location ... which you can see in the browser address bar (unless chrome calls it something else) that's like `https//some.domain/folder1/folder2/filename.html` ... so you need to put a path relative to /folder1/foder2/filename.html` for the image ... or just use an absolute path `/assets/Pngs/ThemesIcon/NewTheme.png` can work too

Answer (score 1):

According to the folders structure, you provided.

You need backward by one folder with `../`.

So the path will be

```
themeButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('../assets/Pngs/ThemesIcon/Theme1.png')"
```

Comment: I still don't agree... it depends on the html page and there's no evidence of that in the question